# how to get data from android signalr invoke

Tags: java, android, signalr

How can can retrieve the array from invoke method? The invoke method works, but I couldn't find how I can get the array from it in Java client.

```
   HubConnection hubConnection;
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create(Constants.BASE_LOCAL_HUB_URL).withAccessTokenProvider(Single.defer(() -> {
            // Your logic here.
            return Single.just(token);
        })).build();
        hubConnection.invoke(UserViewModel[].class, "GetUsers");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke returns a `Single<T>` where T is the type you specified (`UserViewModel[]`).

So you need to use the return value by subscribing to the Single. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rxjava/rxjava_single_observable.htm

The quickest way to test it is working is to do:

`UserViewModel[] arr = hubConnection.invoke(UserViewModel[].class, "GetUsers").blockingGet();`